# Need to union data within rows and get rid of duplicate data within each row in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe in Databricks that produces the following output:

| Field Name |
| --- |
| A, B |
| C,E |
| A,D,F |
| B,C,G |

I need to find a way to union these rows and get rid of duplicate values to create something like this:

| Field Name |
| --- |
| A, B, C, D, E, F, G |

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a group by and collect_set.

```
df2 = df.groupBy(F.lit(1)).agg(F.collect_set('Field Name').alias('Field Name'))
```

Comment: It worked for the most part but for some reason the collect_set didn't remove duplicate values, just grouped everything together.

Answer (score 1):

Try something as below -

```
data = [("A,B",), ("C,E",), ("A,D,F",), ("B,C,G",)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=["Field_Name",])

df.show()

+----------+
|Field_Name|
+----------+
|       A,B|
|       C,E|
|     A,D,F|
|     B,C,G|
+----------+
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import re

remove_dupes = udf(lambda row: set(row), StringType())
comma_rep = udf(lambda x: re.sub(',$|^,','', x))

(df.withColumn("Field_Name", collect_list(col("Field_Name")))
   .select(comma_rep(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(remove_dupes(array_join("Field_Name", "")), "\\]", ""), "\\[", "")).alias("Field_Name"))
   .select(split(col("Field_Name"), ", ").alias("Field_Name")) 
   .select(explode("Field_Name")).filter("col != ''") 
   .select(array_join(collect_list("col"), ",").alias("Field_Name"))
).show(truncate=False)

+-------------+
|Field_Name   |
+-------------+
|A,B,C,D,E,F,G|
+-------------+
```